# Django : login() within Sign In form clean() or in the view ?

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms, django-views

I have a sign in form and a lost password form.
Currently in my clean method in the sign in form I got :

```
user = authenticate(username=self.cleaned_data['login'],
password=self.cleaned_data['password'])
```

In my view, when my form is valid I need to log the user in so I use
login() but it requires a user object. I have 3 ideas but I don't know
which one is safe or safer :

1) put self.user instead of user in the clean method and then in the
view do login(request, myform.user). => don't know if this is safe to
add variables with self in a form.

2) put login() directly in the form clean method instead of the view.
=> seems a little strange to write it there.

3) Do again in the view :

```
user = authenticate(username=self.cleaned_data['login'],
password=self.cleaned_data['password'])
```

=> not really DRY compliant...

Or maybe is it better to put authenticate() in the view instead of the form clean() ? Writing all this I kinda think it would be better to do that.

I have question with my lost password form since I need to set a new
password which also requires a user object and then use send_mail().

What would you do ?

Thanks in advance,
Nolhian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) put self.user instead of user in the clean method and then in the
>   view do login(request, myform.user). => don't know if this is safe to
>   add variables with self in a form.

It's safe. As a matter of fact this is how [django admin auth form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/forms.py#L20) and [pinax accounts app works](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/blob/master/account/forms.py#L86).